# Imaginary components in Discrete Fourier Transform of Gaussian?

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, python, fast-fourier-transform

I am trying to understand Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), after only having experience with the continuous transformation. The natural idea was to try to understand DFT on the simplest function, being an exponential, which should transform into an exponential too. To check this in practice, I've drafted up a Python script to perform DFT on a 6D Gaussian.

Surprisingly, the result seems to have both real an imaginary parts. Based on arguments from the continuous Fourier transform, I would only expect an imaginary part if the function is not even - which the Gaussian should be. The grid is centered symmetrically around zero, so there is no issue with numerical asymmetry either.

Should imaginary numbers appear in the DFT of a six-D Gaussian, and, if yes, what is the significance of this observation?

I believe my Python script is correct, but just in case, here is the implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fftn

def sixdgauss(coords):
    return np.exp(-np.pi * (coords[0] ** 2 + coords[1] ** 2 + coords[2] ** 2 +
                            coords[3] ** 2 + coords[4] ** 2 + coords[5] ** 2))


nx, ny, nz = 8, 8, 8
xx, yy, zz = np.linspace(-2, 2, nx), np.linspace(-2, 2, ny), np.linspace(-2, 2, nz)

nxp, nyp, nzp = 8, 8, 8
xxp, yyp, zzp = np.linspace(-2, 2, nxp), np.linspace(-2, 2, nyp), np.linspace(-2, 2, nzp)

XX, YY, ZZ, XXP, YYP, ZZP  = np.meshgrid(xx, yy, zz, xxp, yyp, zzp)

gauss = sixdgauss((XX, YY, ZZ, XXP, YYP, ZZP))

print(fftn(gauss))
```

---

**Edit:**
As it had been pointed out to me in the comments below, the issue is already present for the 1D case; running `xx = np.linspace(-4,4,16); fft( np.exp(-np.pi * xx**2) )` results in imaginary result too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use simpler examples when you’re looking into such things. The same thing already happens in one dimension.

The transform is real if the input is symmetric about the origin. The origin is at $0$, not in the middle of the interval. The transform doesn’t know that you used the coordinate value $0$ to generate the function value in the middle of the interval.

Comment: I don't think I get the idea; the middle of the interval is at $0$. The interval (on each axis) has the points $\{ -2.0 , -1.43, -0.86, -0.29,  0.29, 0.86,  1.43,  2.0 \}$

Comment: @Szgoger: No, $0$ is just the value of your coordinates at the middle of the interval. You’re not passing your coordinates to the FFT, only the function values, so it has no way of knowing where you imagined the coordinate origin to be when you produced the function values. All it gets is the function values. By definition, it interprets them as values at equidistant points of a periodic lattice with the origin at the value with index $0$.

Comment: I understand your point about the function not knowing about the coordinate grid; these are exactly the sort of nuances I did not foresee just from studying the continuous case. Curiously, however, if I do `xx = np.linspace(0,4,16); fft( np.exp(-np.pi * xx**2) )`, then now the grid is equispaced starting from $0$ with $0$ being the first element in the generated values (it is also 1D, thank you for pointing out the unnecessary complexity) - yet the result is still imaginary.

Comment: @Szgoger: That's not a symmetric function either. You’re just passing one half of a symmetric function to the FFT; again, the FFT has no way of knowing that you’re imagining it to be mirrored symmetrically. You’ll get real-valued output if you pass it an array of values that’s *actually* symmetric when periodically extended. So the upper half of the array needs to contain the values of the lower half mirrored.

Comment: @Szgoger: Note that your original input was a lot closer to being symmetric in this sense than this new one, which doesn’t have any symmetry at all. The original input was symmetric about the index $-\frac12$, so you just had to shift it by $\frac12$.

Comment: This issue of symmetry is quite confusing. However, I have found an illustration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166879/do-i-need-to-call-fftshift-before-calling-fft-or-ifft) for a similar issue in Matlab, highlighting the `fftshift/ifftshift` keywords that seem to be quite general. Indeed, for reasons I yet to understand, calling `ifftshift` on my coordinate arrays returns real results from DFT as it seems to capture the ''correct'' symmetry of the DFT implementation.